# java Runtime exception

Tags: android

```
TextView txtOtherMatches = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtOtherMatches);
txtOtherMatches.setText("Other Matches");
```

i m getting this error while running application  and i m just assigning simple text to Textview at run time ..... 
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your TextView in the xml has exactly the same id: `android:id="@+id/txtOtherMatches"`
2. Check that you don't have more than one `res/layout` folder (e.g., `layout-normal`, `layout-large` or `layout-land`) and, if you do, make sure that your TextView is present in the layourt corresponding to your device/emulator
3. Check that it was added to the current View (most probably, through some `ViewGroup`)
4. If everything else fails, clean the Eclipse project and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

`txtOtherMatches` is probably `null` because it doesn't exist in the current view.When you use `findViewById` the view must be in the "contentview" you've set with `setContentView`, or added later tot the view. You can't find any "random" view that has an ID somewhere, it must actually be "present" in your current view.

If the view is NOT in the xml you're using already, but somewhere else in one of your xmls, you must use an `inflater` to get the View, and add it with `View.add()`

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpfull if you provide a few more lines before that one.
But my guess is Nanne is right.

Try to add a safety check:
(this wouldn't change the code flow)

```
if(txtOtherMatches == null) {
  throw new NullPointerException("darn, the R.id.txtOtherMatches is not in the dialog")
}
```

(on the other hand Nanne mistakenly mentions 'current view' while I'm sure he meant the 'dialog' view.
Put some more meat if you need further assistance ;)